# Is there a way to transfer money from a vanguard settlement account to wise.com

Tags: vanguard

One can not link a bank account to ones vanguard account if their name isn't on the bank account. So is there any way to transfer money from a vanguard settlement cash account to wise.com?

Answer (score 3):

1. Open bank account in your name
2. Transfer from Vanguard to that account.
3. Transfer from that account to Wise
4. Profit?